WCF client unable to connect to server after TLS certificate change
I have a WCF web HTTP service (.Net Framework 4.7.1) running in AWS that is consumed by a number of WCF clients (.Net Framework 4.7.1). The clients are multi threaded C# services. Whenever the TLS certificate for the web service is updated the clients are unable to connect. I was originally running with the security configured as follows:
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
  <message establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false" clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>

When using this form of security the issue was fixed by simply restarting all of the client services. I recently simplified the security, now it is:
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>

However with my most recent certificate change the client services are unable to connect, the re-start has no effect. The error I am seeing in the clients is as follows:
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'wcf-server.com'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

The certificate doesn't appear to be the issue.  I updated my root CA bundle and configured openssl to use that new CA bundle, and was able to connect using openssl. Using every other metric I can find confirms the certificate is ok.
As a stop gap measure I have done the following:
var client = new ServiceModelClient();
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication
{
    CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
    RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
};

This fixes the issue but means nothing is being validated. I have been pulling my hair out over this, any suggestions or help very much appreciated.

Do you make sure that the version of the certificate is the same as on the server, such as TLS 1.1 and 1.2.

This was caused by the validation dates for the certificate being in local time, and I had made the assumption that they would be in UTC.
